# Use sed to capture only param of function

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In my text file I have a special name (treated as a macro) i.e.: `MYFUNCTION[myParam]`

Now I'd like to use sed to get name of used param (in above example it is `myParam`) and based on it searched for a value in a dictionary which I use to replace text `myParam`.

I managed to create a sed instruction to find a group but it also print other words, i.e.:

```
echo "some text MYFUCNTION[paramName]" | sed -e "s/MYFUNCTION\[\([a-Z]*\)\]/\1/"
```

results in the following output:

```
some text paramName
```

I'd like to get in output just only:

```
paramName
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

By including the text before MYFUNCTION in the regex as `.*`, like this:

```
echo "some text MYFUNCTION[paramName]" | sed -e "s/.*MYFUNCTION\[\([a-Z]*\)\]/\1/"
```